# How to show custom 404 page using sw-toolbox sw-precache libraries for service-worker

Tags: service-worker, sw-precache, sw-toolbox

I have an SPA which makes various http calls to get content from third party service and show content on the page.
How do I configure /use sw-toolbox and sw-precache libraries, such that if http call fails due to being offline it shows a custom 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this b specifying a default router using

```
toolbox.router.default = "yourDefaultRoute";
```

more information on this can be found here : https://googlechrome.github.io/sw-toolbox/usage.html#the-default-route

Comment: defaultRoute works when the page being rendered is not available. My scenario is that the page (which is already cached) is making an internal http call which returns a 404 and is handled by the catch of the promise. I want to show a custom 404 from the catch.